# Eloquent - edit table rows and return new result data - old data retrieved

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a form where the user can edit, create or delete shipping methods.
The user sends the form and the data is updated.

I want to return the user's shipping methods after they are edited.
But I seem to get the old data back, instead of the updated data.

```php
$user = \App\User::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();

$user->shipping_methods->each(function($method) {
    $method->delete();
});
$methods = [];
foreach ($request->input('methods') as $method) {
    $methods[] = new \App\ShippingMethod($method);
}

$user->shipping_methods()->saveMany($methods);

return response()->json($user->shipping_methods->toArray());
```

(at the moment the code just deletes the old shipping methods and replaces them with the new ones). I am using eloquent relations to get the shipping methods.

So when I do:

```php
return response()->json($user->shipping_methods->toArray());
```

how come I don't get the new results, instead I get the results from before the update? Is it using the results from the first `$user->shipping_methods` at line 3? Should I "refresh" the query somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reload the relationship:

```php
return response()->json($user->load('shipping_methods')->shipping_methods->toArray());
```

You can also simplify the whole line:

```php
return $user->load('shipping_methods')->shipping_methods;
```

Comment: Great, thanks I got the shipping methods, but there was some eager loaded stuff in the previous code that didn't get included with this "load" method, but I could add it to the the load method, like: return response()->json($designer
                        ->load('shipping_methods','shipping_methods.zone.countries','shipping_methods.supplier')

Answer (score 0):

The `saveMany` method of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` return instace of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and you must manually set relations

```
$shipping_methods = $user->shipping_methods()->saveMany($methods);
$user->setRelation('shipping_methods', $shipping_methods);

return response()->json($user->shipping_methods->toArray());
```